# PHP wont display data and is not showing errors

Tags: php, mysql

most of the keywords here are in norwegian 
THIS RIGHT HERE IS THE THING IM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH 
it wont display (not even the errors) its supposed to display "bilde" as background image in div boxes so that you upload pictures, but nothing pops up, not even the errors. would be nice if anyone could help me.

if i enable error reporting the site wont load

```
 $sql = "SELECT bilde FROM meme"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<div class='box' style='background-image: url({$row[bilde]});  background-size: 100%; width: 90%; height: 35%;'></div>";
      }
      } else {
           echo "0 results";
      }
```

here is the insert into database line

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "mydb"; //her skriver du navn på databasen

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$bilde = $_REQUEST['bilde'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO meme (bilde) VALUES ('$bilde') ";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Vellykket";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Det oppsto en feil <br> $sql. <br><br>";
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo "<br><br><a href='memepage.php'>Tilbake</a>";
```

and lastly the form

```
<form action="insert.php">
       <p class="link">Link her:</p> <br>
       <input type="text" name="bilde"> <br>
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Fullfør" method="post">
```

Comment: view page source, what does `<div class='box' style='background-image: url(` show??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php site wont fetch and display data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455920/php-site-wont-fetch-and-display-data)

Comment: @smith wait what? it doesnt show up in source

Comment: `if i enable error reporting the site wont load` This sounds like an issue in itself...when you turn on reporting, what does the error(s) say?

Comment: the site now loads when i enable error reporting but how do i see what the errors are? @Rasclatt

Comment: Well, if you turn on error reporting using `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page, you may have the error appear inside a tag so it doesn't show in the browser, but rather in the source of the html, so you look at the source to see if there are any errors. You might have `<div class='box' style='background-image: url(<br>Fatal Error: whatever error message here....`

Comment: @Rasclatt  $result = $conn->query($sql); <br> it said that line 37 was the prob and thats line 37

Comment: What is the error though? Can't get property of object or something?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /Users/kevin2112/Desktop/It 1/SQL/SKOLEPROSJEKT/memepage.php on line 37

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Users/kevin2112/Desktop/It 1/SQL/SKOLEPROSJEKT/memepage.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/kevin2112/Desktop/It 1/SQL/SKOLEPROSJEKT/memepage.php on line 37

Comment: Your database is not included (or not included properly) so it can't find `$conn`.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR U ARE GOLD <3 <3 <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)